# Getting blank value when using CALCULATE to return data from 1 year ago

Tags: powerbi, dax

Trying to return loss provision ratio (loan provision/total assets) but for 1 year in the past based on the most recent date available. `MO[Total]="11"` is total loss provision, `MO[Total]="15"` is total assets, `MO[Data_Date]` is all dates. When I break these apart I get correct values, but when I combine them into a divide function it always returns blank. See code below:

```
Loss Provision BS LY =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( MO[Total] ),
        MO[Line_Number] = "11",
        DATEADD ( LASTDATE ( MO[Data_Date] ), -1, YEAR )
    ) * -1,
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( MO[Total] ),
        MO[Line_Number] = "15",
        DATEADD ( LASTDATE ( MO[Data_Date] ), -1, YEAR )
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you saying that both the numerator and the denominator return a non-zero, non-blank value when you evaluate them individually (*including* the DATEADD argument) but not when you try to take the ratio?

Comment: If both calculate functions work, maybe try adding the values into a variable above the divide, then using the variables in your divide.  Also, I would use divide(num, den, 0).  The 0 handles divide by zero errors.